# Opening/Closing Multiple Divs with JQuery slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I am using Jquery's slideToggle() to open and close my main menu. The slideToggle() works perfectly.

What I need to do is get the slideToggle to close a div when a different one is opened. I have tried so many different ways to achieve this but I haven't been able to.

I found the below suggestion on stackoverflow:

[uses the id of the  tag to trigger slideToggle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223873/show-hide-toggle-multiple-divs-by-id)

What I found with that suggestion is that everytime I click on each menu item the page jumps to the top (like its being reloaded) and I didnt like that.

I also found this little bit of code:

[uses the id of the of the div](http://jsfiddle.net/u7Y2r/44/)

I tried to add a third box to that fiddle to see what happened but it didn't work in the same way the first 2 boxes did and I couldn't figure out why.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
            <div class="menu-item-1">
                <a href="#">Recovery</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item-2">
                <a href="#">Forensics</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item-3">
                <a href="#">Erasure</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item-4">
                <a href="#">Training</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item-5">
                <a href="#">Products</a>
            </div>
```

And this is what my javascript looks like:

```
  $( ".menu-item-1" ).click(function() {
    $( ".recovery-bg" ).slideToggle("fast", "easeOutBack");
});

$( ".menu-item-2" ).click(function() {
    $( ".forensic-bg" ).slideToggle();
});

$( ".menu-item-3" ).click(function() {
    $( ".erasure-bg" ).slideToggle();
});

$( ".menu-item-4" ).click(function() {
    $( ".training-bg" ).slideToggle();
});

$( ".menu-item-5" ).click(function() {
    $( ".product-bg" ).slideToggle();
});
```

Here is the HTML code for the divs that slideToggle():

```
<!--Expanding Recovery Menu-->
      <div class="recovery-bg arrow_box_recovery toggle hidden-phone">
    <div class="container expand">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2 offset1">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href=""><p>Data <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="span2 offset1">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href=""><p>Raid <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2 offset1">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href=""><p>Forensic <br/> Data Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2 offset1">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href=""><p>Tape <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/Expanding Recovery Menu-->
```

Ive gone through a couple of other tutorials aswell but in them I noticed that some people dont have `href` in their  tag and I want to avoid stuff like that if I can.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: where are the markup for the opened/closed elements like `recovery-bg`

Comment: I have added the html for the divs that slide Toggle(). In my css I have just set .recovery-bg to display none. When you click it is visible.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7Y2r/189/

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have with that code is that when I add another box it doesnt work in the same way, see here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g93wy/) Fiddle. If you can see what Im doing wrong and correct me that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make some minor markup changes like

```
<div class="menu-item menu-item-1" data-target=".recovery-bg">
    <a href="#">Recovery</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item menu-item-2" data-target=".forensic-bg">
    <a href="#">Forensics</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item menu-item-3" data-target=".erasure-bg">
    <a href="#">Erasure</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item menu-item-4" data-target=".training-bg">
    <a href="#">Training</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item menu-item-5" data-target=".product-bg">
    <a href="#">Products</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle recovery-bg">
    recovery-bg
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle forensic-bg">
    forensic-bg
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle erasure-bg">
    erasure-bg
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle training-bg">
    training-bg
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle product-bg">
    product-bg
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $bgs = $('.menu-toggle');
    $('.menu-item').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
        $bgs.not($target).filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nwPFa/)

Comment: Would you mind explaining some of the jquery? I can see you have created a variable $bgs and your storing menu-toggle in there and then you have the .click function which fires slideToggle() what does the last line of code do? I think its checking to see if the div opened is not the target and then if it isnt it slides it up and closes it.

Comment: To all the div's which are toggled we add a class called `menu-toggle` as shown above. then again in the `menu-item-x` elements we add a class called `menu-item` and a attribute called `data-target` which contains the selector for the `div` that has to be toggled. In the click handler we first toggles the the div that is targeted then we hide any other `menu-toggle` element that might be visible - that is the last line

Comment: Your answer works @arun I found an alternative solution aswell and I would like to use it the only problem is everytime I click on the menu-items <a> tag the page looks like its re-loading and I want to stop the page reload. Can you help? Here is the jquery  `$(".trigger").click(function(){
    var divToToggle = $( $(this).find("a").attr('href') );
    $(".toggle:visible").not(divToToggle).hide();
    divToToggle.slideToggle("slow");
  });
`